# Different Template for Drupal 7

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7

Am new in drupal. so am work with the latest version Drupal 7. In that how can i differentiated between the front page and other pages. i have page.tpl.php file only. am using marinelli Themes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should consider marking some answers to your questions as accepted to get a better response.  See the FAQ: [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2):

Chek out [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) to see the naming conventions for different template types.

In your case you want 2 separate page template files, one called `page.tpl.php` which is the default, and one called `page--front.tpl.php` which will only be active for the content designated as the site front page.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a page-front.tpl.php that will be used for the front page. Remember to clear your caches after you create this file.

Comment: page-front.tpl.php was for Drupal 6. He is using Drupal 7. See Clive's answer below. (Note the two hyphens ` -- ` in the file name.)